# html form with file upload

Tags: html, css

At the moment I'm trying to get a script to work.  I want to make a form where I can upload a file and send it to a specific mail address. 
The form data gets deliverd in my mail. but the uploaded file show's up as text and not as a attachment. Here's my code:

```
<HTML>
<body>
    <!-- Start of form -->
    <div class="container">
        <form id="gform" method="POST"
        action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwLZpEa2iDgug8yVh-s9qIvo0H0GK9_O0ioLjStFBdAlqjGcgw/exec">

          <label for="fname">Naam & achternaam</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" name="Naam" placeholder="Vul hier uw naam in">

          <label for="lname">Email</label>
          <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Vul hier uw email in">

          <label for="wnplts">Woonplaats</label> 
          <input type="text" id="wnplts" name="woonplaats" placeholder="Voer hier uw woonplaats in">

          <label for="nummer">Nummer</label>
          <input type="text" id="nummer" name="nummer" placeholder="Voer hier uw nummer in">

          <label for="salaris">Salaris (op fulltime basis)</label>
          <input type="number" id="salaris" name="salaris" placeholder="">

          <label for="file">Upload CV</label> <br>
          <input type="file" id="CV" name="CV" accept="file_extension" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <br> <br>

          <label for="subject">Motivatie</label>
          <textarea id="subject" name="Motivatie" placeholder="Schrijf hier uw motivatie" style="height:200px"></textarea>

          <input type="submit" value="Submit">

        </form>
      </div>
      <!-- End of form -->


</body>
</HTML>
```

This is my CSS:

```
input[type=text], select, textarea {
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    padding: 12px; /* Some padding */  
    border: 1px solid rgb(167, 167, 167); /* Gray border */
    border-radius: 4px; /* Rounded borders */
    box-sizing: border-box; /* Make sure that padding and width stays in place */
    margin-top: 6px; /* Add a top margin */
    margin-bottom: 16px; /* Bottom margin */
    resize: vertical /* Allow the user to vertically resize the textarea (not horizontally) */
}

input[type=number], select, textarea {
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    padding: 12px; /* Some padding */  
    border: 1px solid rgb(167, 167, 167); /* Gray border */
    border-radius: 4px; /* Rounded borders */
    box-sizing: border-box; /* Make sure that padding and width stays in place */
    margin-top: 6px; /* Add a top margin */
    margin-bottom: 16px; /* Bottom margin */
    resize: vertical /* Allow the user to vertically resize the textarea (not horizontally) */
}

input[type=email], select, textarea {
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    padding: 12px; /* Some padding */  
    border: 1px solid rgb(167, 167, 167); /* Gray border */
    border-radius: 4px; /* Rounded borders */
    box-sizing: border-box; /* Make sure that padding and width stays in place */
    margin-top: 6px; /* Add a top margin */
    margin-bottom: 16px; /* Bottom margin */
    resize: vertical /* Allow the user to vertically resize the textarea (not horizontally) */
}

/* Style the submit button with a specific background color etc */
input[type=submit] {
    background-color: rgb(141, 0, 0);
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=file] {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    padding: 12px 20px;
    border: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;

}

/* When moving the mouse over the submit button, add a darker green color */
input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}

/* Add a background color and some padding around the form */
.container {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

I'm also using Google Scripts. It retrieves the data and send it as a email back.  Here is the code:

```
var TO_ADDRESS = "themail@gmail.com"; // Email

function formatMailBody(obj) { // function to spit out all the keys/values from the form in HTML
  var result = "";
  for (var key in obj) { // loop over the object passed to the function
    result += "<h4 style='text-transform: capitalize; margin-bottom: 0'>" + key + "</h4><div>" + obj[key] + "</div>";
    // for every key, concatenate an `<h4 />`/`<div />` pairing of the key name and its value, 
    // and append it to the `result` string created at the start.
  }
  return result; // once the looping is done, `result` will be one long string to put in the email body
}

function doPost(e) {

  try {
    Logger.log(e); // the Google Script version of console.log see: Class Logger
    record_data(e);

    var mailData = e.parameters; // just create a slightly nicer variable name for the data

    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: TO_ADDRESS,
      subject: "Contact form submitted",
      // replyTo: String(mailData.email), // This is optional and reliant on your form actually collecting a field named `email`
      htmlBody: formatMailBody(mailData)
    });

    return ContentService    // return json success results
          .createTextOutput(
            JSON.stringify({"result":"success",
                            "data": JSON.stringify(e.parameters) }))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } catch(error) { // if error return this
    Logger.log(error);
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": e}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  }
}


/**
 * record_data inserts the data received from the html form submission
 * e is the data received from the POST
 */
function record_data(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)); // log the POST data in case we need to debug it
  try {
    var doc     = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet   = doc.getSheetByName('responses'); // select the responses sheet
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1; // get next row
    var row     = [ new Date() ]; // first element in the row should always be a timestamp
    // loop through the header columns
    for (var i = 1; i < headers.length; i++) { // start at 1 to avoid Timestamp column
      if(headers[i].length > 0) {
        row.push(e.parameter[headers[i]]); // add data to row
      }
    }
    // more efficient to set values as [][] array than individually
    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
  }
  catch(error) {
    Logger.log(e);
  }
  finally {
    return;
  }

}
```

Does anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: You need to set the proper `enctype` on the form for file uploads to work ...

Comment: I got this right now:
<input type="file" id="CV" name="CV" accept="file_extension" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: You need to specify it on the `form` element ...

Comment: Can u give me an example? I just tried but it does not work for me :(

Comment: Well it doesn’t look like your Google Script is currently set up to handle file uploads to begin with? Right now it tries to output every single POST parameter in text form ... so you’ll have to go and research how to append an attachment to an e-mail using this first of all.

Comment: put your attribute enctype to the `form tag` instead of particular `input tag`.

Answer (score 0):

I understood your question as follows.

- In your script, data from HTML form is received at `doPost(e)`, and the data can be parsed, and the string data is created by `formatMailBody()`.

  - These work fine.
- You want to send the string data created by `formatMailBody(obj)` as an attachment file.

  - This doesn't work

If my understanding is correct, how about the following modification?
HTML created by `formatMailBody()` is converted to a blob, and sent as an attachment file. When you use this modified script, please replace the attachment filename `"samplename.html"` to yours.

#### From :

```
MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: TO_ADDRESS,
  subject: "Contact form submitted",
  // replyTo: String(mailData.email), // This is optional and reliant on your form actually collecting a field named `email`
  htmlBody: formatMailBody(mailData)
});
```

#### To :

```
MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: TO_ADDRESS,
  subject: "Contact form submitted",
  // replyTo: String(mailData.email), // This is optional and reliant on your form actually collecting a field named `email`
  //  htmlBody: formatMailBody(mailData)
  attachments: [Utilities.newBlob(formatMailBody(), MimeType.HTML, "samplename.html")] // Added
});
```

#### Reference :

- [MailApp.sendEmail](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(Object))

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: I've tried your modification, but for any reasons I don't get the file delivered in my inbox. Without this modification, any attachment gets deliverd as text. With this modifcation it does not get deliverd neither as text or as a file.

Do u have any idea?

Comment: @wouter mirck I'm sorry for the inconvenience. Can I ask you about the sample data retrieved from ``formatMailBody(mailData)``? In my environment, I confirmed that this works. So I would like to compare the difference.

Comment: This is the result:
{"result":"success","data":"{\"CV\":[\"Capture.PNG\"],\"Motivatie\":[\"This is a TEST\"],\"Naam\":[\"Test\"],\"salaris\":[\"2400\"],\"nummer\":[\"123456789\"],\"email\":[\"1234@gmail.com\"],\"woonplaats\":[\"Amsterdam\"]}"}




I'm still receiving the mail, but my mail is now blank with this modification. Can u send the full script of what u changed? i did not work for me :(
I'm not the best with google scripts haha

Comment: @wouter mirck I would like to confirm about the data. ``formatMailBody(mailData)`` returns ``{"result":"success","data":"{\"CV\":[\"Capture.PNG\"],\"Moti‌​vatie\":[\"This is a TEST\"],\"Naam\":[\"Test\"],\"salaris\":[\"2400\"],\"nummer\‌​":[\"123456789\"],\"‌​email\":[\"1234@gmai‌​l.com\"],\"woonplaat‌​s\":[\"Amsterdam\"]}‌​"}``?

Comment: Yes the data result is a succes. But the mail that i received is blank.

Comment: @wouter mirck From the script of your question, it seems that ``function formatMailBody(obj) {}`` returns string data. But you say that ``function formatMailBody(obj) {}`` returns object. I confuse about this. Can I ask you about this? If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.